# all combinations of a set of numbers that sum up to a specific value

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

Is there a systematic way to find all the combinations of a set of numbers that sum up to a specific value?

For example, I have the numbers $36, 27, 12, 6, 4$, and $2$. I want all sets of these numbers that sum up to $39$. Clearly, $36$ can be removed from the problem, but that doesn't happen in general.

I can find {$27,12$} and {$27,6,4,2$} by inspection and think that may be it. But is there a way to quickly find all of these sets for a large problem?

Comment: I think the only systematic way is a systematic search through all the possibilities. Look at the _knapsack problem_: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem

Comment: Yeah, that's the problem I'm working with. I have a knapsack problem with an equality constraint and want to find facet-defining inequalities to my integer program.

Comment: Well at least you know now it's hard and don't need to beat yourself up for not solving it. If you're lucky there's something in your particular application that will allow for some optimization, shortening search paths.